# sql where closure with modified column value

Tags: sqlite

I have a master table containing URLs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MasterTable (url, masterId, PRIMARY KEY(url), UNIQUE(masterId));
```

An url string looks like this: `file:///Users/user1/Pictures/rubus_and_apple.jpeg`.

Now I want to lookup on the url column but only on the filename `rubus_and_apple` and not on all url string. (Meaning only on the last component of the url w/o extension).

For example I want to look the keyword `rubus` and get the url:`file:///Users/user1/Pictures/rubus_and_apple.jpeg`.

I need my query to be like:

```
SELECT masterId
FROM MasterTable
WHERE <url last component w/o extension> LIKE '%/rubus%';
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT masterId
FROM MasterTable
WHERE url LIKE '%/rubus.%';
```

Please note that this expression is not-SARGable so it won't use index.

**EDIT:**

```
WITH MasterTable(MasterId, url) AS(
  VALUES(1, 'file:///Users/user1/Pictures/rubus_and_apple.jpeg')
)
SELECT *
FROM MasterTable
WHERE REPLACE(url,RTRIM(url,REPLACE(url,'/','')),'') LIKE '%' || 'rubus' || '%';
      -- part of string after last /
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=2bd165449e081c2ecf5ddfe85f175ed4)**

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear. For simplification, I need to look in the filename w/o the extension.

Comment: Edited again... I need the query to be something like: `SELECT masterId
FROM MasterTable
WHERE <url last component w/o extension> LIKE '%/rubus%`;

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @Sanich I just extract last part of url and compare with provided string i.e. 'rubus'

Comment: Why `LIKE '%' || 'rubus' || '%'` and not `LIKE '%rubus%`? What does it do?

Comment: @Sanich It's the same Feel free to use any version